# Writing functions over the same variable in a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I am working with some baseball data and am trying to figure out how to write functions that operate on all columns in a list of like data frames.  So for instance, I have on base percentage for a team for each game played, what I want to do is run `shift(cumsum(teamname$OBP))` for each data frame in the list in order to find the cumulative sum of their OBP for the season, and then shift the data so each row will contain the previous days cumulative sum. Is there a way to do this specifically with an apply function so that it runs the same function over all the data frames?

Below are some of the variables that I'm looking to apply this over:

```
> head(teams$SEA[27:34])
# A tibble: 6 x 8
     RA   OBP   SLG  wOBA  wOPS    RC    PE BBSOr
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     7 0.375 0.452 0.326 0.777  6.20 0.623 0.6  
2     4 0.314 0.442 0.298 0.740  7.29 0.610 0.556
3     4 0.419 0.861 0.478 1.34  13.8  0.9   0.444
4     7 0.3   0.559 0.350 0.908  6.48 0.424 0.4  
5     5 0.368 0.441 0.354 0.795  6.74 0.590 0.4  
6     8 0.422 0.568 0.418 0.985 10.1  0.610 0.636
```

My list looks like this.

```
> summary(teams)
    Length Class       Mode
SEA 34     spec_tbl_df list
PIT 34     spec_tbl_df list
ARI 34     spec_tbl_df list
COL 34     spec_tbl_df list
SLN 34     spec_tbl_df list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Data**

I gave the Pirates a lower OBP to show the function runs over the data frames separately, and also because they seemed the most likely candidate of the five non-SEA teams to have such a poor OBP :)

On future questions, please add sample data that others can easily paste into R. `dput()` is a useful function for doing so.

```
library(data.table)

SEA <- read.table(text = "     RA   OBP   SLG  wOBA  wOPS    RC    PE BBSOr
     7 0.375 0.452 0.326 0.777  6.20 0.623 0.6  
     4 0.314 0.442 0.298 0.740  7.29 0.610 0.556
     4 0.419 0.861 0.478 1.34  13.8  0.9   0.444
     7 0.3   0.559 0.350 0.908  6.48 0.424 0.4  
     5 0.368 0.441 0.354 0.795  6.74 0.590 0.4  
     8 0.422 0.568 0.418 0.985 10.1  0.610 0.636",
                  head = TRUE,)
PIT <- SEA
PIT$OBP <- PIT$OBP/2
ARI <- SEA
COL <- SEA
SLN <- SEA

teams <- list(SEA = SEA, 
              PIT = PIT, 
              ARI = ARI, 
              COL = COL, 
              SLN = SLN)
```

**Solution**

```
lapply(teams,
       function(x){
         x$OBP_cumsum <- shift(cumsum(x$OBP))
         x
       })

$SEA
  RA   OBP   SLG  wOBA  wOPS    RC    PE BBSOr OBP_cumsum
1  7 0.375 0.452 0.326 0.777  6.20 0.623 0.600         NA
2  4 0.314 0.442 0.298 0.740  7.29 0.610 0.556      0.375
3  4 0.419 0.861 0.478 1.340 13.80 0.900 0.444      0.689
4  7 0.300 0.559 0.350 0.908  6.48 0.424 0.400      1.108
5  5 0.368 0.441 0.354 0.795  6.74 0.590 0.400      1.408
6  8 0.422 0.568 0.418 0.985 10.10 0.610 0.636      1.776

$PIT
  RA    OBP   SLG  wOBA  wOPS    RC    PE BBSOr OBP_cumsum
1  7 0.1875 0.452 0.326 0.777  6.20 0.623 0.600         NA
2  4 0.1570 0.442 0.298 0.740  7.29 0.610 0.556     0.1875
3  4 0.2095 0.861 0.478 1.340 13.80 0.900 0.444     0.3445
4  7 0.1500 0.559 0.350 0.908  6.48 0.424 0.400     0.5540
5  5 0.1840 0.441 0.354 0.795  6.74 0.590 0.400     0.7040
6  8 0.2110 0.568 0.418 0.985 10.10 0.610 0.636     0.8880

$ARI
  RA   OBP   SLG  wOBA  wOPS    RC    PE BBSOr OBP_cumsum
1  7 0.375 0.452 0.326 0.777  6.20 0.623 0.600         NA
2  4 0.314 0.442 0.298 0.740  7.29 0.610 0.556      0.375
3  4 0.419 0.861 0.478 1.340 13.80 0.900 0.444      0.689
4  7 0.300 0.559 0.350 0.908  6.48 0.424 0.400      1.108
5  5 0.368 0.441 0.354 0.795  6.74 0.590 0.400      1.408
6  8 0.422 0.568 0.418 0.985 10.10 0.610 0.636      1.776

$COL
  RA   OBP   SLG  wOBA  wOPS    RC    PE BBSOr OBP_cumsum
1  7 0.375 0.452 0.326 0.777  6.20 0.623 0.600         NA
2  4 0.314 0.442 0.298 0.740  7.29 0.610 0.556      0.375
3  4 0.419 0.861 0.478 1.340 13.80 0.900 0.444      0.689
4  7 0.300 0.559 0.350 0.908  6.48 0.424 0.400      1.108
5  5 0.368 0.441 0.354 0.795  6.74 0.590 0.400      1.408
6  8 0.422 0.568 0.418 0.985 10.10 0.610 0.636      1.776

$SLN
  RA   OBP   SLG  wOBA  wOPS    RC    PE BBSOr OBP_cumsum
1  7 0.375 0.452 0.326 0.777  6.20 0.623 0.600         NA
2  4 0.314 0.442 0.298 0.740  7.29 0.610 0.556      0.375
3  4 0.419 0.861 0.478 1.340 13.80 0.900 0.444      0.689
4  7 0.300 0.559 0.350 0.908  6.48 0.424 0.400      1.108
5  5 0.368 0.441 0.354 0.795  6.74 0.590 0.400      1.408
6  8 0.422 0.568 0.418 0.985 10.10 0.610 0.636      1.776
```